# Can't login with express+mysql, register works

Tags: mysql, express

I've tried various ways to make it work, but I can't get the login page to work, and the issue I believe is on the express side.

```
//index.js
const  findUserByEmail  = (email, cb) => {
    return  mc.query('SELECT * FROM user_login WHERE email = ?',[email], (err, row) => {
            cb(err, row)
    });
}

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const  email  =  req.body.email;
    const  password  =  req.body.password;

    findUserByEmail(email, (err, user)=>{
        if (err) return  res.status(500).send({ "message":  'Server error!', "status": '500'});
        if (!user) return  res.status(404).send({ "message":  'User not found!', "status": '404'});
        const  result  =  bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
        if(!result) return res.status(401).send({ "message":  'Password not valid!', "status": '401'});
        const  expiresIn  =  24  *  60  *  60;
        const  accessToken  =  jwt.sign({ id:  user.id }, SECRET_KEY, {
            expiresIn:  expiresIn
        });
        res.status(200).send({ "user":  user, "access_token":  accessToken, "expires_in":  expiresIn, "message":  'Success!', "status": '200'});
    });
});
```

I have register working, but when I try the above code, with the account in the database, it throws this error in express:

```
C:\JSProjects\IonicProjectV2\express-auth-demo2\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined
    at Object.bcrypt.compareSync (C:\JSProjects\IonicProjectV2\express-auth-demo2\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:265:19)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either password or user.password is undefined, so bcrypt complains about this.

Please add console.logs like this, and see which one is undefined.

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    console.log(password);

    findUserByEmail(email, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ "message": 'Server error!', "status": '500' });
        if (!user) return res.status(404).send({ "message": 'User not found!', "status": '404' });

        console.log(user);
        const result = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user[0].password);
        if (!result) return res.status(401).send({ "message": 'Password not valid!', "status": '401' });
        const expiresIn = 24 * 60 * 60;
        const accessToken = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, SECRET_KEY, {
            expiresIn: expiresIn
        });
        res.status(200).send({ "user": user, "access_token": accessToken, "expires_in": expiresIn, "message": 'Success!', "status": '200' });
    });
});
```

**Edit**: the user password was inside the user[0].password, so using this in bcrypt.compareSync  solved the problem.

Comment: console.log(user.password); came up as undefined.

Comment: @baumli and what if console.log(user) instead of console.log(user.password)?

Comment: console.log(password) shows the text entered into the password field.

Comment: @baumli console.log(user) instead of console.log(user.password)

Comment: Sorry, didn't se you changed it:  
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 4,
    name: 'First Last',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password:
     '$2a$10$SJf9tqTRxNe5g6HnWNys2OxbmMcQg48LDb20QzezCVkZZ97Ly1xv6',
    created_at: 2019-10-16T18:03:19.000Z } ]

Comment: @baumli so the password is inside the user[0].RowDataPacket.password, so you need to pass this to the compareSync instead of user.password

Comment: @baumli did you try?

Comment: Still getting an error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined

Comment: @baumli are you sure? Did you restarted to node process after code changes?

Comment: @baumli Or can you try user[0].password?

Comment: Yes, the error actually crashes the express service.

Comment: Ok can you try user[0].password?

Comment: Using user[0].password doesn't crash it, the new error is:
Server listening at http://localhost:3000
ReferenceError: password is not defined
    at router.post (C:\JSProjects\IonicProjectV2\express-auth-demo2\index.js:88:17)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200973/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-baumli).